# Keep DTD after XML Transform

Tags: .net, xml, dtd

I am transforming an XML document but after the transform my DTD goes away and also the first line which tells the XML version is missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

The code I am using to transform the XML file is:

```
// Load the style sheet.
            var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xslt.Load("XSLTFile1.xslt");

            // Create the writer.
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                            {
                                Indent = true,
                                IndentChars = "\t",
                                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto,
                                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                            };

            var mydoc = XDocument.Load("Doc1.xml"); 

            var writer = XmlWriter.Create("Doc2.xml", settings);

            // Execute the transform and output the results to a file.
            if (writer != null)
            {
                xslt.Transform(mydoc.CreateReader(), writer);
                writer.Close();
            }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the XML declaration, you need to make sure in your `XmlWriterSettings` that [`OmitXmlDeclaration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is set to `false`:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                   {
                     Indent = true,
                     IndentChars = "\t",
                     ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto,
                     Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                     OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
                    };
```

As for the DTD "going away" - since you are transforming the document, you should add a new DTD declaration to the transformed document.

Without the `xsl` and `xml` files, it is difficult to tell for certain. Can you edit your question and add them?

Answer (score 0):

hey thanks for the reply. I did

```
writer.WriteDocType(mydoc.DocumentType.Name, mydoc.DocumentType.PublicId, mydoc.DocumentType.SystemId, mydoc.DocumentType.InternalSubset);
```

And it worked. Yes I also have

```
OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
```

Thanks